# Boxplots in matplotlib: Markers and outliers

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, boxplot

I have some  questions about [boxplots](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo.html) in matplotlib:

**Question A**. What do the markers that I highlighted below with **Q1**, **Q2**, and **Q3** represent? I believe **Q1** is maximum and **Q3** are outliers, but what is **Q2**?

[image]

**Question B** How does matplotlib identify **outliers**? (i.e. how does it know that they are not the true `max` and `min` values?)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's a graphic that illustrates the components of the box from a [stats.stackexchange answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/149178). Note that k=1.5 if you don't supply the `whis` keyword in Pandas.

[image: annotated box in a boxplot]

The boxplot function in Pandas is a wrapper for `matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot`. The [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) explain the components of the boxes in detail:

**Question A:**

> The box extends from the lower to upper quartile values of the data, with a line at the median.

i.e. a quarter of the input data values is below the box, a quarter of the data lies in each part of the box, and the remaining quarter lies above the box.

**Question B:**

> whis : float, sequence, or string (default = 1.5)
>
> As a float, determines the reach of the whiskers to the beyond the
>   first and third quartiles. In other words, where IQR is the
>   interquartile range (Q3-Q1), the upper whisker will extend to last
>   datum less than Q3 + whis*IQR). Similarly, the lower whisker will
>   extend to the first datum greater than Q1 - whis*IQR. Beyond the
>   whiskers, data are considered outliers and are plotted as individual
>   points.

Matplotlib (and Pandas) also gives you a lot of options to change this default definition of the whiskers:

> Set this to an unreasonably high value to force the whiskers to show
>   the min and max values. Alternatively, set this to an ascending
>   sequence of percentile (e.g., [5, 95]) to set the whiskers at specific
>   percentiles of the data. Finally, whis can be the string 'range' to
>   force the whiskers to the min and max of the data.

Comment: I like this answer as it's specific to matplotlib and in particular the whisker range.

Answer (score 107):

A picture is worth a thousand words. Note that the outliers (the `+` markers in your plot) are simply points **outside** of the wide `[(Q1-1.5 IQR), (Q3+1.5 IQR)]` margin below.

[image]

However, the picture is only an example for a normally distributed data set. It is important to understand that matplotlib does **not** estimate a normal distribution first and calculates the quartiles from the estimated distribution parameters as shown above.

Instead, the median and the quartiles are calculated directly from the data. Thus, your boxplot may look different depending on the distribution of your data and the size of the sample, e.g., asymmetric and with more or less outliers.

Comment: So `99.3%` of your data is contained **inside** of the wide `[(Q1-1.5 IQR), (Q3+1.5 IQR)]` margin above (also known as the whiskers). Thus all the ticks outside of that represent only `0.7%` of your data.

Comment: Based on the answer from @Joooeey and my understanding of matplotlib.boxplot I don't think this answer is strictly correct (or at leat doesn't totally answer the original question). The whiskers don't cover  [(Q1-1.5 IQR), (Q3+1.5 IQR)], they're at the outermost data points inside this range but outside [Q1,Q2] - otherwise the whiskers would always be symetric which they aren't.

Comment: Not sure I follow @DavidWaterworth. `[(Q1-1.5 IQR), (Q3+1.5 IQR)]` don't need to be symmetric to 0.

Comment: I don't mean symetrical to zero, I mean Q1-1.5 IQR == Q3+1.5 IQR, this is actually the "fence" which you can see in the answer from Joooeey, the actual bars plotted by matplotlib at the end of the whisker aren't at this location, they're inside it.

Comment: i.e. in your chart above if the largest and smallest observations inside +/- 2.698\sigma were -2\sigma and +1.7\sigma then this is where the whisker bars will be, not at +/- 2.698\sigma

Comment: Thanks @DavidWaterworth are you perhaps saying that in OP's specific plot, we don't really have `[Q1-1.5 IQR, Q3+1.5 IQR]` but instead `[Q1 -k *IQR, Q3 + k*IQR]` for a `k !=1.5`?

Comment: No, regardless of k matplotlib doesn't plot the whisker bars at [Q1 -k *IQR, Q3 + k*IQR], "the upper whisker will extend to last datum less than Q3 + k*IQR)" and "the lower whisker will extend to the first datum greater than Q1 - k*IQR"  (the documentation uses whis in place of k). See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html under "whis"

Comment: Got it now. Thanks @DavidWaterworth

Comment: I just switched my accepted answer :) @DavidWaterworth

Answer (score 27):

The box represents the first and third quartiles, with the red line the median (2nd quartile). The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) gives the default whiskers at 1.5 IQR:

```
boxplot(x, notch=False, sym='+', vert=True, whis=1.5,
        positions=None, widths=None, patch_artist=False,
        bootstrap=None, usermedians=None, conf_intervals=None)
```

and

> whis : [ default 1.5 ]
>
> Defines the length of the whiskers as a function of the inner quartile range. They extend to the most extreme data point within ( whis*(75%-25%) ) data range.

If you're confused about different box plot representations try reading [the description in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot).

Answer (score 24):

The image below shows the different parts of a boxplot.

[image]

Quantile 1/Q1: 25th Percentile

Interquartile Range (IQR): 25th percentile to the 75th percentile.

Median (Quantile 2/Q2): 50th Percentile.

Quantile 3/Q3: 75th Percentile.

I should note that the blue part are the whiskers of the boxplot.

The image below compares the box plot of a normal distribution against the probability density function. It should help explain the "Minimum", "Maximum", and outliers.

[image]

"Minimum": (Q1-1.5 IQR)

"Maximum": (Q3+1.5 IQR)

As zelusp said, 99.3% of data is contained within 2.698σ (standard deviations) for a normal distribution. The green circles (outliers) in the image below are the remaining .7% of the data. [Here](https://builtin.com/data-science/boxplot) is a derivation of how those numbers came to be.

Comment: I really LOVE the explanation and the figure you used. Can you also provide the code for us to replicate the last draw? I think that it can have also nice pedagogic purposes!

Comment: ups, there is a missing license and I would love to use the last figure of your answer in an appendix of my thesis :) (citing correctly your work)

Comment: I added a license: https://github.com/mGalarnyk/Python_Tutorials/blob/master/LICENSE. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Perfectly! :) Grazie!

Answer (score 13):

In addition to seth answer (since the documentation is not very precise regarding this):
Q1 (the wiskers) are placed at the maximum value below 75% + 1.5 IQR

(minimum value of 25% - 1.5 IQR)

This is the code that computes the whiskers position:

```
        # get high extreme
        iq = q3 - q1
        hi_val = q3 + whis * iq
        wisk_hi = np.compress(d <= hi_val, d)
        if len(wisk_hi) == 0 or np.max(wisk_hi) < q3:
            wisk_hi = q3
        else:
            wisk_hi = max(wisk_hi)

        # get low extreme
        lo_val = q1 - whis * iq
        wisk_lo = np.compress(d >= lo_val, d)
        if len(wisk_lo) == 0 or np.min(wisk_lo) > q1:
            wisk_lo = q1
        else:
            wisk_lo = min(wisk_lo)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this - I found the discrepancy in my plots (compared to the docs value of *Q3+1.5*IQR*) and was glad to see your clarification. TBH though, I am a bit confused by the `or` expression: the `else` parts make sense, but the `or` seems impossible... e.g. for the Q3 part, `len(wisk_hi)==0` means "if we find no elements below the `hi_val`" - how can this happen? Q3 is found by splitting the data on the median, and taking the median of the upper half... by definition there will be values lower than hi_val - and what does the second part of the `or` mean? Any advice most welcome.

Comment: I can only agree with you, @ttsiodras, that `q3` should be part of the `d` array and fulfill the condition to `np.compress`, so it should also be in the array the max is taken from. Maybe the code is just "to be save", or to make it more obvious to the reader that `wist_hi` cannot be smaller than `q3`.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case this can benefit anyone else, I needed to put a legend on one of my box plot graphs so I made this little .png in Inkscape and thought I'd share it.

edit: to clarify a bit more,  The whiskers end at the farthest data point within the 1.5 * IQR interval.

[image]