# How matplotlib calculate the value of lower and upper extreme in boxplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I tried to understand how matplotlib draws a graph. This is the code that I write.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

age=[20,22,22,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,26,26,30]
df=pd.DataFrame(age, columns=['age']) 
df['age'].describe()
```

This is the data printed out

```
count    14.000000
mean     23.857143
std       2.348720
min      20.000000
25%      23.000000
50%      23.500000
75%      24.000000
max      30.000000
Name: age, dtype: float64
```

I calculated the value IQR, L, U

```
IQR = Q3 - Q1= 24 – 23 = 1
L = Q1 – 1.5 * IQR = 23 – 1.5 * 1 = 21.5
U = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR = 24 + 1.5 * 1 = 25.5
```

However, the graph generated by matplotlib is different from what I calculate:

```
df.boxplot(column = ['age'])
```

[image]

The value of L and U extreme is 22 and 24 (not 21.5 and 25.5)

What is the formula for L and U (lower and upper extreme) that matplotlib uses?

Thanks a lot for pointing out my mistakes?

Comment: The following duplicate specifically answers this question [What exactly do the whiskers in pandas' boxplots specify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082568/what-exactly-do-the-whiskers-in-pandas-boxplots-specify). From that answer, **the upper whisker will extend to last datum less than Q3 + whis*IQR**

Answer (score 1):

The values you calculated are the **bounds**, and *not* **L** and **U**.

**L** and **U** are the mimimum/maximum points **from the data** that are within 1.5 IQR from Q1/Q3.

You calculate `21.5` as the lower bound, but the smallest point in your data that is greater than or equal that bound is `22`.

Similarly, the upper bound you calculated is `25.5`, but the largest point in your data that is less than or equal that bound is `24`

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.